# Calculating the time and space complexity of function f2

Tags: time-complexity, space-complexity

I have this function and I am trying to calculate time and space complexity, I got an answer but I am not sure if it's correct, I'd like to know whether this is correct or not

```
   void f1(int n)
    {
        int i,j,k=0;
        for(int i=n/2; i<=n; i++)
        {
            for(int j=2; j<=i; j*=2)
            {
                k+=n;
            }
        }
        
        free(malloc(k));
    }
```

My results:

For the outer for loop it's pretty straightforward O(n).

For the inner loop, we have log((n/2)+i) each iteration, so basically log(n) each iteration.

And so the total time complexity is O(n*log(n))

For space complexity, it's O(k) whenever k receives it's final value, since final value for k is k+n n*log(n) times, we have that after all iterations, k=n^2*log(n), and so space complexity is O((n^2)*log(n)).

Is this correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: The time complexity is correct, but the space complexity is just O(1).

Comment: @MoB. is it not allocating that space first, then freeing it?

Comment: The size of the allocated space is constant, i.e., independent of the input `n`, hence it is O(1). (Unless we are talking about a programming language where `int` refers to the type of arbitrary length integers.)